# How to set On/Off Timers on Android 9 using ADB?

Tags: android, timer, adb, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to set an automatic on/off timer for a device that is running Android 9 (For examples sake let's say I want it to turn on at 9 AM and turn off at 5PM) This must happen daily.

I want this to be done using adb commands so that it can be automated down the line.

If I go into settings I can navigate as so: `Settings > Accessibility > Scheduled Power on and off`
once in here I can set the *Power off time*, *Power on time* and the 2 relative *Repeat*s

Any changes I make (physically or via adb) are then required to be confirmed by pressing the *Save Settings* button at the bottom of the screen.

> Pressing the *Save Settings* button triggers the introduction of multiple variables:
> **close_machine_time_hour**
> **close_machine_time_mins**
> **open_machine_time_hour**
> **open_machine_time_mins
>
> power_off_cycle_mode**
> **power_on_cycle_mode
>
> power_off_date**
> **power_on_date**
> **power_way**
> **machine_time_secs**

Of which the 2 I am most concerned about are the last 2 as these seem like odd variables to only introduce when activating a niche setting (I feel as though they should either be there always)

**Question 1:** would be is this a standard Android feature? Or is this something that has been done for custom ROM?

I have tried setting all the settings as they appear in settings grabbed using command `adb shell settings list system`

They are set individually using the commands below:

```
adb shell settings put system timer_power_switch_settings 1
adb shell settings put system close_machine_time_hour 09
adb shell settings put system close_machine_time_mins 00
adb shell settings put system open_machine_time_hour 17
adb shell settings put system open_machine_time_mins 00
adb shell settings put system power_off_time 9:00:16
adb shell settings put system power_on_time 17:00:16
adb shell settings put system power_off_cycle_mode 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-
adb shell settings put system power_on_cycle_mode 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-
```

You'll note that in essence I am setting the time twice, which is quite odd.

The key thing is that none of this works unless I physically press the save button (despite showing visual feedback on the device screen that values change as I alter them via adb). Which is fine for 1 device but will become quite laborious if it needs to be done for 30+ devices at a time.

**Question 2:** Is there to simulate this *Save Settings* button click without simulating a tap on screen? Or to bypass this setting entirely?

**Question 2.A:** Is there a way to continuously monitor activity using an adb command? so I can run it, then click the button, and it will show me what's going on in the background?